# Equivalent of RadialOutside for Graph VertexLabels

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, charts

I'm creating a circular graph and want the labels to be placed on the outside of the vertices in a circular manner on the outside of the graph. I've been playing around with the `Placed` function, but haven't got very far. I'm looking for results similar to `"RadialOutside"` that's available to charts. This seems like it should be easy, but I haven't been able to get anywhere.

```
g = Graph[CompleteGraph[26], VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed["Name" , Top], {i, 26}]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
g = Graph[CompleteGraph[26], 
VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed["Name", {{0,0}, 
{-Cos[Pi/2 + 2 i Pi/26], .25 - Sin[Pi/2 + 2 i Pi/26]}}], {i, 26}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: (+1) but with ImageSize -> 900 , labels are one the vertices

Answer (score 9):

Not to detract from PatoCriollo's excellent answer, but just to show that there is always a "there is also...".

Furthermore, the following, to my surprise, is not as fragile as I thought it might be with respect changes in `ImageSize` and in the vertex count of `CompleteGraph`.

```
vc = GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[26]];
g = Graph[EdgeList@CompleteGraph[26],
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[{16, Bold, "Panel"}], ImagePadding -> 20,
  VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed["Name", .5 + Pi vc[[i]]], {i, 26}]]
```

[image]

```
gr = With[{vc = GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[#]]},
    Graph[EdgeList@CompleteGraph[#],
     VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[{16, Bold, "Panel"}], 
     ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> #2,
     VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed["Name", .5 + Pi vc[[i]]], {i, #}]]] &;

Row[gr[#, 300] & /@ {10, 16, 26}]
```

[image]

```
Row[gr[16, #] & /@ {200, 300, 500}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind having a `Graphics` rather than a `Graph` object, you can use 
`` GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart `` which combines a `PieChart` with the edges of a graph:

```
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[CompleteGraph[16], 
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[.3]]]
```

[image]

Use the options `LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#2[[2]], "VerticalCallout"] &)` and `ChartLabels -> None` to get

[image]

Use `CompleteGraph[32]` as the first argument to get

[image]

To remove the annuli, use `ChartElementFunction -> None`:

```
 GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[CompleteGraph[25], 
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[25], "RadialCallout"], 
  ImageSize -> 450, ChartElementFunction -> None, 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]] /.  _Disk :> {}
```

[image]

Use `ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[25], "VerticalCallout"]` to get

[image]

Comment: How'd you find this one? It's very cool. Also presumably the layout info from here could be reinserted into a `Graph` object to get a `Graph` in the end.

Comment: @b3m2a1, i was browsing through the functions in ``??GraphComputation```. The name sounded interesting and it worked in my first try with a graph input.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `IGVertexMap` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) to compute label coordinates for circular embeddings.

Here's an example

```
IGVertexMap[
 Placed["Name", {0.5 + 1.8 Normalize[#], {.5, .5}}] &,
 VertexLabels -> GraphEmbedding,
 IGLayoutCircle[g]
]
```

[image]

This is more concise (and IMO more readable) than any of the other presented solutions. Also, it does not rely on a certain vertex naming, like the accepted answer.

This is how it works:

- `IGLayoutCircle` creates a layout centred on `{0,0}` (unlike `"CircularEmbedding"`).
- `Placed["Name", {pos, epos}]` will place the point `epos` within the label at location `pos` within the vertex itself. Both are given in scaled coordinates running from 0 to 1.

Here's a more complex example copied from the IGraph/M documentation:

```
IGVertexMap[
 Function[{name, coord},
  Placed[
   name,
   {{.5, .5}, -0.8 Normalize[coord] + {.5, .5}},
   Rotate[#, Mod[ArcTan @@ coord, Pi, -Pi/2]] &
  ]
 ],
 VertexLabels -> {VertexList, IGVertexProp[VertexCoordinates]},
 IGLayoutCircle@ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "FamilyGathering"}]
]
```

[image]

Should you need to order vertices differently along the circle, you can use `IGReorderVertices`. This function preserves graph properties, which is useful if you want to also style the graph based on some properties with `IGVertexMap`/`IGEdgeMap`.