# Positioning of vertex labels on graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

How can I position the vertex labels outside of the "circle" in `CircularEmbedding`?

For example executing the code snippet

```
RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[30, 0.2], 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

we get something like:

[image]

The upper right labels are positioned outside the "circle", but the lower left labels are positioned in the "circle". Is there an easy way to position all of the out?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Equivalent of RadialOutside for Graph VertexLabels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63449/125)

Comment: @kglr yeap! it solved my problem. Thanks!